# Hiding a PDF in html for download on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, download

I am facing a situation in my application where i need to add a pdf download link on to my page, but i cannot refer to any relative or absolute path for the file, I need to host my pdf inside the html only.

Is there any way to do this, using basic HTML and JavaScript?

Details summary of situation is as below :

there is an application which owned by someone else, i am customizing if for a particular client.

we are given a provision to place some html(s) in a directory which are used in a few pages in the application.

these htmls are not used with href or include in the product application, but are picked up by the product's java code and are added in the response, thus keeping a PDF in the same folder  as my HTML and providing relative URL wont work here.. and putting absolute URL is also not a solution as this needs to work across multiple environments.

Comment: This sounds like an XY question. What is the reason you need to do this? If it's to restrict access to the file there are better methods, a token system for example.

Comment: -> there is am application which owned by someone else, i am customizing if for a particular  client. 
-> we are given a provision to place some html(s) in a directory which are used in a few pages in the application.
-> these htmls are not used with href or include in the product application, but are picked up by the product's code and are added in the response, thus keeping a PDF in the same folder and providing relative URL wont work here..

Does that help in knowing the issue ?

Comment: Upload those files to any Cloud Storage Service, such as Google Drive (make sure that those files are publicly available) and then copy the URL of files and reference them inside the HTML.

Comment: Cross domain links are generally not appreciated in big applications, permissions, rights and and many other question come in picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Data_URI_scheme&oldid=690276682) links:

```
<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,...">download PDF!</a>
```

Possibly together with the [download attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download):

```
<a href="..." download="my_file.pdf">...</a>
```

E.g. http://jsbin.com/gutahugoci/ (PDF is from [here](http://mirror.unicorncloud.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/europecv/examples/minimal.pdf)).

To encode in [base64](http://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) use `base64 -w0 my_file.pdf > my_file.pdf.b64`

**Disclaimer:** Please notice that I said "you *can* use", not "you *should* use. This should only be a last resort thing to do for PDFs, because the HTML file will become exceedingly big and your client might ask if your are kidding them.

Comment: my pdf was 180Kb only.. so no worries on pdf size... thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

why don't you encode the url

/download_pdf.php?id=r4yhr4hrb4rd54hddb4

Where r4yhr4hrb4rd54hddb4 is and encoded id?

Comment: How could this help in hosting a hidden pdf in a html ?